# Power Query - Parse a very weird file

Tags: excel, m

I have a file that looks like this:

```
AA,DATA,DATA,DATA
BB,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
ZZ,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
ZZ,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
CC,DATA,DATA
ZZ,DATA,DATA,DATA
ZZ,DATA,DATA,DATA
ZZ,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
```

As you can see, it's very unfriendly.  The ZZ starting lines means they're related to the previous record; therefore in my example BB is split on 3 lines and CC is split on four lines.
What I would like to achieve in Power Query (Excel 2013) is to obtain a table that will contains only AA, BB and CC record.  The ZZ would be concatenated to their respective BB and CC records.  The number of ZZ record may vary.
I'm new at Power Query and I guess that I started with a too much heavy problem to deal with ;)  Any specific idea on how I should construct table and/or list to help me would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty positive you can't do that in PowerQuery. You could use VBA to get the data right, then put it into PowerQuery.  Here's some code that could do that.

```
Sub NormalizeData()

    Dim sFile As String, lFile As Long
    Dim vaLines As Variant
    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim dc As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim lStart As Long

    'Open file and read in all the data
    sFile = "K:\testfile.txt"
    lFile = FreeFile

    Open sFile For Input As lFile
    vaLines = Split(Input$(LOF(lFile), lFile), vbNewLine)
    Close lFile

    For i = LBound(vaLines) To UBound(vaLines)

        vaData = Split(vaLines(i), ",")

        If vaData(0) <> "ZZ" Then
            'Output existing dictionary if it exists
            If Not dc Is Nothing Then Debug.Print Join(dc.Items, ",")

            'Create a new dictionary and start at the first column (0)
            Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary
            lStart = 0
        Else
            'starts with ZZ so skip the first column
            lStart = 1
        End If

        'Add the data to the dictionary
        For j = lStart To UBound(vaData)
            dc.Add dc.Count + 1, vaData(j)
        Next j

    Next i

    'Output the last dictionary
    If Not dc Is Nothing Then Debug.Print Join(dc.Items, ",")

End Sub
```

Comment: I understand your VBA logic and that's what I would like to accomplish using Power Query.  I'm quite positive this can be done :)  I was thinking about trying to derive a row number with an index and then define another column where the row number is the same as the previous one in case the first column is ZZ..  I would then be able to group records together and play with lists/tables to manipulate the string...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and it's possible that my solution wouldn't work back then. But this PQFL works well when I try it in PowerBI Desktop.

```
let
  RecordKey = (t,n) => Table.Range(t,n,1){0}[Key],

  NeedsMerged = (t,n) =>
    try
      if RecordKey(t,n+1) = "ZZ" then true else false
    otherwise false,

  MergeWithNext = (t,n) =>
    if NeedsMerged(t,n) then
      let
        thisRow = Table.Range(t, n, 1),
        nextRow = Table.Range(t, n+1, 1)
      in  
        {
        true,  
        Table.Range(t, 0, n) &
        Table.TransformColumns( thisRow, {"Data", (_) => _ & nextRow{0}[Data] } ) &
        Table.Range(t, n + 2)
        }
    else {false,t},

  DoNeededMerging = (t,n) =>
    if Table.RowCount(t) < n then t
    else
      let 
        res = MergeWithNext(t,n),
        resp = res{0},
        tbl = res{1}
      in
        if resp then
          @DoNeededMerging(tbl,n)
        else
          @DoNeededMerging(tbl,n+1),

  Filename = "C:\the_data_file.csv",
  DataTable = Table.FromList(Lines.FromText(Text.FromBinary(File.Contents(Filename))), Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(","), {"Key","Data"}, null, ExtraValues.List),
  DataTable2 = DoNeededMerging( DataTable , 0)

in
  DataTable2
```